# Supported GPU's not showing

Tags: gpu, hardware

I currently have 2 R9 280's and according to blender all GPU's with the new OpenGL and GCN 1ste gen are supported. But in blender 2.79 and 2.82 I can't seem to use it in any way. I know AMD is not that great but I am saving up for a 2060 and the dual R9 280's should work for now. can someone please help me to fix this. and command line codes I have to run or scripts I can use.

Comment: I used blender gpu debug gpu and the output was this txt = https://pastebin.com/fvWvW7L8

Comment: Okay, so I downloaded blender 2.78. it shows my 2 gpu's in blender 2.78 why not 2.79 or 2.82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your AMD R9 280 card doesn't fulfill the [requirements for GPU rendering in Blender 2.8x](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). You would either need a

- Nvidia graphics card with CUDA compute capability 3.0 or higher
- AMD graphics card from GCN second generation or later

[The AMD R9 280 has the GCN first generation architecture.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_Rx_200_series)

> **CUDA**
>
> CUDA requires graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of Nvidia graphics cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards. CUDA GPU rendering is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

---

> **AMD**
>
> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with GCN generation 2 and above. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of GCN generations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#Iterations) with the GCN generation and supported graphics cards.
>
> AMD OpenCL GPU rendering is supported on Windows and Linux, but not on macOS.

Please note that the requirements for GPU rendering are higher than the [minimum requirements for running Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

> These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using the graphics card requires slightly different [requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware).