# Blender 2.82a cannot use CUDA or OPENCL

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, interface, gpu

I am running into an issue that I am unable to solve! I am using blender 2.82a, I have an NVIDIA GT630 installed in my system, and am using Ubuntu 20.04. I want to use my GPU to render my scene, but when I want to activate CUDA in the preference, Blender cannot find any usable device! I have checked as follow:

1 - Additional driver being used
[image: Ubuntu Addtional Drivers]
Used both driver but same issue when I try to activate CUDA in Blender preference.

2 - Installed and Re-installed NVIDIA driver
[image: Nvidia X settings]
Driver seem to be installed correctly.

3 - Getting the CUDA info from the command line
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

4 - Uninstalled and re-installed blender 2.82, and 2.82a still cannot activate the device in Blender, even with portable version.
[image: Blender 2.82a]

5 - Use Blender 2.79b portable version and it let me select the CUDA device.
[image: Blender 2.79b]

I would be grateful for anyone to bring any suggestion as so far I have tried the following links:

[How to make CUDA work in Ubuntu so as to enable GPU rendering in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82528/how-to-make-cuda-work-in-ubuntu-so-as-to-enable-gpu-rendering-in-blender)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342538

But still cannot get Blender 2.8x to select the CUDA device.

Thank you kindly

Jean

---

Additional information:

the nvidia-smi returns the following:

Tue Jun  2 09:11:19 2020

| NVIDIA-SMI 340.108    Driver Version: 340.108

| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |

| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |

|   0  GeForce GT 630      Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |

| 52%   64C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    457MiB /  4095MiB |     N/A      Default |

| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |

|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |

|    0            Not Supported                                               |

Is the n630gt not supported on blender 2.8x?

Comment: The GPU doesn't have the required CUDA compute capability. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173449/supported-gpus-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

Install CUDA toolkit from the Ubuntu repo:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo reboot
```

After CUDA install, without reboot, Blender won't start at all, so, reboot is very important!

I had the very same problem. That worked for me.

Comment: this fails on Ubuntu 20.04 due to unmet dependencies: nvidia-profiler and nvidia-cuda-dev. Every attempt I've made to install a cuda tookit results in the installation of nvidia-driver-460 which doesn't work with my GeForce GTX 470.